# Crazy random normals. Can anyone explain?

Tags: edit-mode, normals, error

crazy random normals are showing up not attached to my object when "show normals" is enabled. the positions cycle through a few different shapes.
object is a simple bottle modeled from a circle solidify applied. subsurf level 2 not applied. I believe this started happening when I joined the cap back with the bottle as one object. cap was modeled with geometry borrowed from the bottle.

this doesn't seem to have any effect on anything I'm doing, but it's not the first time I've seen this and I'm curious if anyone can explain. (bottle faces are oriented correctly. selection is making it look red)[image][image: crazy normals]

Comment: That does look strange. Can you [share](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file) the blend file?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cUnC9HVOl2xb0IJl_sFHgx3JNZkevekE/view?usp=sharing
you might need to recalculate the normals to recreate. you can get different variations by recalculating the normals over and over